# Difference between account age on network profile and the site itself

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

The Stack Overflow profile of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21440243/starship-is-go-for-launch) says

> Member for 10 months

However, their [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/24172783/starship-is-go-for-launch?tab=accounts) says for that same account

> Joined 10 days ago

What's going on here?

Comment: Without looking into the details, I'm going to take a wild guess that it was the result of multiple accounts being merged.